# Why I can't scroll to the first column?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to ask why I can't scroll to the first column in my table?

I want to have table with specific width and if resolution gets smaller scroll bar will appears and I will be able to scroll through the all table.

HTML

```
<div id="reservation-calendar">
      <div class="reservation-table">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="time">
                <p>8:30</p>
                <a href="#">There is plus svg</a>
               </td> 
               <td class="plus">There is plus svg</a></td>
               <td class="plus">There is plus svg</a></td>
               <td class="plus">There is plus svg</a></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
#reservation-calendar{
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    .reservation-table{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        overflow-x: auto;
        width: 120rem;
        table{
            width: 126rem;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            tbody{
                display: block;
                tr{
                    .time{
                        width: 6rem;
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                        align-items: center;
                        justify-content: space-between;
                        border: none;
                        padding: none;
                       p{
                        font-size: 2rem;
                        background: blue;
                        color: $white;
                        font-weight: white;
                        padding: 0 0.5rem;
                        padding-top: 0.3rem;
                       }
                       a{
                        text-align: center;
                        margin-top: 0.5rem;
                        svg{
                            width: 2.5rem;
                        }
                       }
                    }
                    .plus{
                        text-align: center;
                        border: 2px solid $text;
                        width: 40rem;
                        padding: 0.5rem;
                        a{
                            svg{
                                width: 3rem;
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/ji-nov-ek/pen/vYrrLmw

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Do you want to scroll horizontally through mouse wheel?

Comment: You set a table width of 126rem. That's big. Try 100% (= screen width).

Comment: I would like to use horizontal scoll bar, so I can scroll and see all table. @Amini

Comment: Your problem is the value of width you've added to the table. They don't match.

Comment: I tried but this not fix my problem, because after that you can't use scroll bar anymore. I want to have specific width of the cells and table and use horizontal scroll bar to see all the table. But problem is I can't scroll through the table (I can't see a first cell). @Michel

Comment: They don't match because I want to simulate smaller resolution. My goal is if I have table with width for example 1200 px and mobile phone with resolution of 400px. I want use the overflow: auto; and see all the table content with horizontal scroll bar on the phone and dont destory the layout. @Amini